# Android google map cuncerent location. Add a new locked marker and draw a line on the google map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

Hey guys so i've been working on this app, wich has a google map and get my location i have this all working,

now im wondering and i know it's possible just not how. How can i make a new marker somewhere on the map (this location is locked and will not change what ever happens) and finally when the phone have your location and the marker location automaticly draw a line between them?

**This is my class code:**

```
class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);


    }


}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );



}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**and this is the idea i like to put in**

```
    Marker marker = googleMap.add(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
    .title("San Francisco")
    .snippet("Population: 776733"));

    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

i hope you guys can help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a Marker I'm doing:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1)).title("marker title").icon(BitmapDescriptorFact‌​ory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_wikipedia));
googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

as you can see in [line 348](https://github.com/barriosnahuel/tourGuide/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nbempire/android/tourguide/component/activity/MapActivity.java) of my application: [Tureame](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nbempire.android.tourguide).

In your code, I think you're adding twice the same marker.

Then, to draw a line between two points, you can follow the example in [Android documentation of Polyline](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html):

```
GoogleMap map;
// ... get a map.
// Add a thin red line from London to New York.
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
    .width(5)
    .color(Color.RED));
```

Comment: I see what you mean with this its kinda what i was thinking about, but in your Markeroptions refering to "eachplace" you have something like a textview where people can but in a random location and you import that location or not? like can i place my Latlng and Longitude cordinates in the () or isnt that posible?

Other question you put the Polyline above the oncreate method?

Comment: Oh sorry @user2422764, I've changed the code to uncouple it from my app domain. eachPlace is just a Place entity with a String and two doubles with latitude and longitude. I retrieve a number of locations near to the user and add all that locations to the map.
I've never used the Polyline, but the example in Android documentation is clear I think so that's why I give you that example. I'd add the polyline after adding both markers but it doesn't matter in which order you add those items to the map because  you can delete the markers and the line will be there because are independent components

Comment: Ah haha i see you changed the code it works now! thank you very much!

Comment: Just one more question, can you see how i can get my cucerent location variable in the 'add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1)' ? :)

Comment: I don't understand.. What do you want me to see in your code? Or what do you want to do and you can't get it working?

Comment: well in my code you see around the bottom '@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)'  so you see it declares a 'latitude and longitude'. i like to have those 2 in my polyline .add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0)) for example. you know how i can get the variables working in the polyline of the latitude and longitude?

Comment: If what you want is getting the lat & long variables from any [Polyline](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html) you can use the [.getPoints()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html#getPoints()) method. Check [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), everything is there.

Comment: well this is usefull aswell, but i more like to get the lat & long from my cuncerent location wich is declared in my code. and put that lat & long in my Polyline, but i dont really get that working now :s

Comment: To get user's current location check [this working code](https://github.com/barriosnahuel/tourGuide/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nbempire/android/tourguide/component/activity/MapActivity.java).
You need to subscribe to location updates and use a [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to be notified of user's location updates. Then when you've the current [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) just use its lat & long values to create the Polyline.